# useState with array giving odd results

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm facing an issue with the react `useState` with arrays,
this is my `teamMembers` state declaration:

```
const [teamMembers, setTeam] = useState();
```

...and I'm filling a form and, on click of a button, updating the `teamMembers` state. the below code is inside a handler:

```
let newTeam = teamMembers || ['Tony Stark'];

console.log(newTeam);    // here it is giving me Tony Stark
setTeam(newTeam);
```

I have used `useEffect` to see the update:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(teamMembers);     // here it is giving me empty array([])
})
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should set to an empty array first:

```
const [teamMembers, setTeam] = useState([])
```

Then:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(teamMembers)
}, [teamMembers])
```

If array ever changes `useEffect` will log an empty array.

Think you're trying to do:

```
const [teamMembers, setTeam] = useState([])

setTeam([...teamMembers, 'Tony stark'])

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(teamMembers)
}, [teamMembers])
```

Answer (score 0):

correction in third block might work:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(teamMembers);     // here it is giving me empty array([])
},[teamMembers]);
```